# Save a max of 5 searches to LocaHost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, localhost, local-storage

I need to be able to save a max of 5 searches to the sidebar. When the user clicks on the search it will re-execute the saved search. Right now I'm using the LocalStorage in order to save these. At the moment I can save the newest search as a string converted from a javascript object. Any help is very much appreciated! Here is the code:

```js
var searchObject = {};

$('.search-button').click(function () { 
  var business = $('#business-name-button').val();
  var industry = $('#industry-button').val();
  var job = $('#job-title-button').val();
  var revenue = $('#annual-revenue-button').val();
  var employeeNumber = $('#number-of-employees-button').val();
  var companyYears = $('#company-years-button').val();
  var locationAll = $('#location-all-button').val();
  var locationSingle = $('#location-single-button').val();
  var locationHeadquarter = $('#location-headquarter-button').val();
  var locationBranch = $('#location-branch-button').val();
  var minorityNone = $('#minority-none-button').val();
  var minorityOnly = $('#minority-only-button').val();
  var womenNone = $('#women-none-button').val();
  var womenOnly = $('#women-only-button').val();
  searchObject = {
    business: [business],
    industry: [industry],
    job: [job],
    revenue: [revenue],
    employeeNumber: [employeeNumber],
    companyYears: [companyYears],
    locationAll: [locationAll],
    locationSingle: [locationSingle],
    locationHeadquarter: [locationHeadquarter],
    locationBranch: [locationBranch],
    minorityNone: [minorityNone],
    minorityOnly: [minorityOnly],
    womenNone: [womenNone], 
    womenOnly: [womenOnly]
  };
  var searchHistory = '';
  if (business != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#business-name-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Business Name: " + '<span>' + searchObject.business + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (industry != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Industry: " + '<span>' + searchObject.industry + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (job != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Job: " + '<span>' + searchObject.job + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (revenue != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Anuual Revenue: " + '<span>' + searchObject.revenue + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (employeeNumber != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "# Of Employees: " + '<span>' + searchObject.employeeNumber + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (companyYears != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Years in  Business: " + '<span>' + searchObject.companyYears + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (locationAll != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "All Locations: " + '<span>' + searchObject.locationAll + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  }; if (locationSingle != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Single Locations: " + '<span>' + searchObject.locationSingle + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (locationHeadquarter != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Headquarter Locations: " + '<span>' + searchObject.locationHeadquarter + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (locationBranch != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Branch Locations: " + '<span>' + searchObject.locationBranch + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (minorityNone != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Omit Minorities: " + '<span>' + searchObject.minorityNone + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (minorityOnly != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Only Minorities: " + '<span>' + searchObject.minorityOnly + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (womenNone != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Omit Women: " + '<span>' + searchObject.womenNone + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  if (womenOnly != '') {
    //   searchObject.business == $('#industry-button').val();
    searchHistory += "Only Women: " + '<span>' + searchObject.womenOnly + "</span> &ensp;&mdash;&ensp;";
  };
  $('.middle-content').show('fast');
  $('.user-instruct').hide();
  $('.saveSearch').prepend(
    "<h5>" + "Search" + "</h5>" +
    "<p>" + searchHistory.slice(0, -19)  + "</p>");
  var saveSearchDisplay = $('.saveSearch').html();
  localStorage.setItem('saveSearch', JSON.stringify( searchObject ));
  localStorage.setItem('saveSearchDisplay', saveSearchDisplay);
  return false;
});

if (localStorage.getItem('saveSearchDisplay')) {
  $('.saveSearch').html(localStorage.getItem('saveSearchDisplay'));
}

var restoredSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('saveSearch'));

/*if(localStorage.getItem('saveSearch')) {
            $('.saveSearch').html(localStorage.getItem('saveSearch'));
        };*/

$('#clearsave').click(function () {
  window.localStorage.clear();
  location.reload();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success search-button" type="button">Search</button>
<div class="section-right-content">
  <h4>Previous Searches</h4>
  <ul class="saveSearch"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have to do this client side, you could try to stringify an array containing five search objects to json.

Comment: I also would recommend using json for all your data structuring needs (not just in JavaScript either!)  It's the most elegant way to store structured data like preferred lists.

Answer (score 1):

The following will error when run here, but can be pasted into the console.

```js
function createCircularQ(maxLength, arr) {
    const q = arr ? arr.splice(0, maxLength) : [];
    q.enqueue = enqueue.bind(null, q, maxLength);
    q.dequeue = q.shift;
    return q;
}

function enqueue(target, maxLength, o) {
   if(target.length === maxLength) {
     Array.prototype.pop.call(target);
   }
   return Array.prototype.unshift.call(target, o);
}

var searches = createCircularQ(5, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searches')));
function search(str) {
    searches.enqueue(str);
    saveSearches();
    // perform search...
}
function saveSearches() {
    localStorage.setItem('searches', JSON.stringify(searches));
}

search('foo');
search('bar');
search('bam');
search('bat');
search('baz');
search('bop');
console.log(JSON.stringify(searches));
searches = null;
searches = createCircularQ(5, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searches')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(searches));
```